# Inner join of table a and table b with selecting only one row of multiple in table b ( row with colum n = max value )

Tags: sql

i am a total beginner in SQL. So i have two tables ( table a and table b ) 
table a holds people with unique IDs,  table b holds multiple rows for each person of table a and also the persons ID ( for a possible join ) . the rows in table b are sorted by the columnn row_number.

How can i select all people but only the row of table b with the highest row_number ?

i hope you could somewhat understand me.

Cheers

Comment: Update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Note: `row_number` is a bad name for a column. Did you mean `row_number() OVER(...)` ?

Comment: what database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right:

```
SELECT a.persons_ID
      ,b.rn 
  FROM A   
INNER JOIN
       (
        SELECT MAX(row_number_column) AS rn
              ,persons_ID
          FROM B 
        GROUP BY persons_ID
        ) sub
     ON sub.persons_ID = A.persons_ID
```

The subselect in the inner joins groups your data of table B. So there will be just one row for each `persons_ID` - the row with the highest `row_number_column`.
Finally just a simple join on persons_ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any other information than the person ID and the last row_number per person, then it is quite trivial. Let's call the first table `person` and the second `visit`:

```
select   person_id,
         max(row_number) max_row_number
from     visit
group by person_id
```

If you need some other information from the *first* table, like `person.name`, then perform the join:

```
select     person.person_id,
           person.name,
           max(visit.row_number) max_row_number
from       person
inner join visit on visit.person_id = person.person_id
group by   person.person_id, 
           person.name
```

If you need some other information from the *second* table, like `visit.present`, then modern databases support the `row_number()` window function (not to be confused with the column that you have):

```
select name, 
       base.row_number,
       present
from (
      select     person.name,
                 row_number() over (partition by visit.person_id 
                                    order by visit.row_number desc) rn,
                 visit.row_number,
                 visit.present
      from       person
      inner join visit on visit.person_id = person.person_id
) base
where rn = 1
```

NB: I would strongly advise to rename the column `row_number` to some other name, as `row_number` is an analytic function in many databases.